# React is undefined while using rollup to bundle as esm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

Rather than having a single bundle for my rollup react app in development, I split it into two bundles. One for the dependencies and one for the app itself.

This way the watch mode stays fast (as it now doesn't has to parse the dependencies continously) and I don't have to write (or use third party) es module wrappers for libraries such as React.

While the code is bundled without any errors, I run into `TypeError: React is undefined` while running it. When I check the network panel in developer tools I do see the dependency bundles getting downloaded.

[Here](https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/blob/feat/sep-bundle/packages/webapp/scripts/build.js) is how I am using rollup with its API.
You can see the rest of the relevant code [here](https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/tree/feat/sep-bundle/packages/webapp).

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure you can parse React `cjs` to `esm` since React has built as `cjs` already. You can check by looking at your dep bundle file then.

Comment: @tmhao2005 I mean it works great when I create a single bundle. Problem seems to coming from React DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the latest `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` version (14.0.0). It was fixed with the merge of [this PR](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/pull/501), but this hasn't been released to NPM yet. I went and built the latest version from GitHub, and used it with the repo in question, and React is now working.

So for now the solution is to use the latest source on GH until the next version is published.